# How to render nested child pages in Comfortable Mexican Sofa

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comfortable-mexican-sofa

So this is what I'm trying to accomplish, but I'm not sure where to start:

I have the following structure of pages:
[image]

On the home page, I want to display each child to of Publications as a section.  The two sections would be Alerts, and New Story of the Week.  Then the latest published child of a section would render within that section.  So on home page I would have the following sections and articles:
Alerts -> Trouble in the East-1-20-2015
News Story of the Week -> Congress Ohverhauls Farm Bill

I've read the CMS wiki, but I don't know how to approach this.  Do I use tags and collections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create a partial to get this working.

Create one here `/app/views/comfy/cms/content/_section_list.html.erb`

Then in the layout for the homepage add `{{cms:partial:section_list}}` to the html where you want the partial to be displayed.

Then in `_section_list.html.erb` do something like:

```
<% @cms_page.children.each do |section| %>
  <h1><%= section.blocks.where(identifier: 'header').first.content %></h1>
  <%= section.children.first.blocks.where(identifier: 'content').first.content %>
<% end %>
```

Note: be sure to get the block identifiers correct, I'm assuming you have a `header` and `content` in the snippet above.

Answer (score 2):

In cms layout that `Publication` is using define a partial tag `{{ cms:partial:foo/bar/articles }}`

Inside that partial you'll have access to `@cms_page`. Now you can render things out.

`@cms_page.children` will give you `Alerts` and `News Story of the Week` pages. Then you can fetch a first child of those pages.

It's using `acts_as_tree` in the back, so it's pretty straightforward.